# Raspberry pi 3+b Raspbian buster lite mp4 boot video

Tags: raspbian, boot, pi-3b+, omxplayer

I am new to the raspberry world and i'm trying to have a video play on startup early on instead of the boot/text that usually shows. I have tried with info from old videos and guides but this hasn't been successful, Is there an idiots guide to making this work? Currently have omxplayer installed and the video I want to play transferred via WinSCP saved in /home/pi/.Thanks